# Flutter Pubget is not working. Getting error of 69

Tags: flutter

```
Connection closed while receiving data
pub get failed
command: "C:\Flutter sdk\Flutter 3.7.5\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\Flutter sdk\Flutter 3.7.5\flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}
exit code: 69
```

Getting exit code 69 when I try to sync flutter sdk 3.7.5

Answer (score 1):

When SDK is not appropriate for the project at that time machine throws this kind of error. I tried many and I got solution when I sync Flutter sdk 3.3.9.